# Microsoft graph api download file content doesn't return doesn't return download URL

Tags: api, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, azure-ad-graph-api

I want to download the content of a file in order to store it in local machine, the request I sent is:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/test/file1.docx:/content
get.addHeader("Accept", "application/octet-stream"),
get.addHeader('Authorization', authcode);
get.addHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-store');
```

the response code is 200 not 302. When I use my personal account the response header is jason object which has Content-Location (it is a download url). So far so good.
But when I use business account, the response code is 200 but there is no downaloadurl/contentlocation/ or anything similar in the response header.
All the permissions I think is fine, the scope in Azure is set to "Files.ReadWrite.All".

PS: I don't want to download the file, I want to download the filecontent.
Any suggestions?

Update: looks like this is known issue, there is already a case for that https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/5637

Answer (score 0):

Could you please share more detailed steps and screenshots?

I tested the API, everything is fine:

[image]

---

Another way is also mentioned in the github issue page:

We can get the `@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl` feom the metedata:

[image]

Comment: Strangely I get 200 in postman as well. I  am wondering can this related to the Azure/app registration setup??

Comment: Not sure about it.  Can you get the @microsoft.graph.downloadUrl ?